# Nested table in table in table in table in div display block not inheriting height

Tags: css, css-tables

Why is wrapper #4 not inheriting the height of its parent table container?
The tables are nested in a display block wrapper, and each nested div is display table, and each table inherits until the innermost one. What is causing this and how can I workaround it?

The jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ubjZT/14/ (edit there was a typo in the old jsfiddle)

html markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="lastunit">
       <div class="wrapper2">
          <div class="wrapper3">
             <div class="wrapper4">
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper
{
    display: block;
    background: black;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body
{
    height: 500px;
}

.lastunit
{
   height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
   background: yellow;
   display: table;
}

.wrapper2
{
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 58.95117540687161%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: table;   
  background: red;
}

.wrapper3
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 display: table;
 background: green;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}

.wrapper4
{
  width: 39.24050632911392%;
  margin-left: 5.4249547920434%;
  margin-right: 5.4249547920434%;                                                      
  margin-top: 6.69077757685353%;                                                  
  height: 88.650306748466%;
  display: table; 
  background: purple;
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ubjZT/20/**

Comment: I only see a red square in your fiddle...also, what's with those crazy %'s in the style rule for `.wrapper4`? Did you mean to set `height: 100%`?

Comment: it should be partly green and partly red. i updated the fiddle, i accidently put a green quote after the green color. those percents are from the real website which im using to set an image size. why is there not purple?

Comment: Okay, after fixing your typo, i see a thin green box, and then a giant red box.

Comment: refresh the page, it should contain wrapper3's background. im using chrome v.27.0.1453.94 on windows 7 desktop

Comment: yeah there should be a purple box too inheriting, using a percentage of the green box's height but its not. dunno why.

Comment: try setting `position: relative` on `.wrapper4`. Also, please post an updated fiddle that works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30999/discussion-between-masu-and-crush)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to set the wrappers to `display: table` here. Just set them to `display: block` (you could, in fact, not set the `display` property at all because `div` defaults to `display: block`)